# Why does typecheck return NoType, even when it's calculated a valid symbol?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

Following on from: [How to Typecheck a DefDef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363542/how-to-typecheck-a-defdef/22386405#22386405)

First, some snippets from my macro:

```
object log {
  def err(msg: String): Unit = c.error(c.enclosingPosition, msg)
  def warn(msg: String): Unit = c.warning(c.enclosingPosition, msg)
  def info(msg: String): Unit = c.info(c.enclosingPosition, msg, force=true)
  def rawInfo(name: String, obj: Any): Unit = info(name + " = " + showRaw(obj))
}

methodsIn(body) foreach { dd => //dd: DefDef
  val name = dd.name.toString
  log.rawInfo(name, dd)
  log.rawInfo(name + ".rhs", dd.rhs)

  try {
    val typechecked = ctx.typecheck(dd.duplicate)
    log.rawInfo(name + ".typechecked", typechecked)
    log.info(name + ".typechecked.symbol = " + typechecked.symbol)
    log.rawInfo(name + ".typechecked.symbol [raw]", typechecked.symbol)
    log.info(name + ".typechecked.symbol.info = " + typechecked.symbol.info)
    log.rawInfo(name + ".typechecked.symbol.info [raw]", typechecked.symbol.info)
    log.rawInfo(name + ".typechecked.tpe", typechecked.tpe)
  } catch { case e: Throwable => log.warn(e.toString)}
}
```

I then feed the macro with this class:

```
class BorgMe(@mymacro val param: Nanites) {
  def one(s: String) = s
}
```

Yes... it's a paradise annotation macro.  But I don't think that's relevant here.

What's confusing me is the log output from that code, which looks like:

```
one = DefDef(
  Modifiers(),
  TermName("one"),
  List(),
  List(List(ValDef(
    Modifiers(PARAM),
    TermName("s"),
    Ident(TypeName("String")),
    EmptyTree
  ))),
  TypeTree(),
  Ident(TermName("s"))
)

one.rhs = Ident(TermName("s"))

one.typechecked = DefDef(
  Modifiers(),
  TermName("one"),
  List(),
  List(List(ValDef(
    Modifiers(PARAM),
    TermName("s"),
    TypeTree().setOriginal(
      Select(
        Select(
          This(TypeName("scala")),
          scala.Predef
        ),
        TypeName("String")
      )
    ),
    EmptyTree
  ))),
  TypeTree(),
  Ident(TermName("s"))
)

one.typechecked.symbol = method one
one.typechecked.symbol [raw] = TermName("one")

one.typechecked.symbol.info = (s: String)String
one.typechecked.symbol.info [raw] =
  MethodType(
    List(TermName("s")),
    TypeRef(
      SingleType(ThisType(scala), scala.Predef),
      TypeName("String"),
      List()
    )
  )

one.typechecked.tpe = NoType
```

Given that the typecheck is succeeding, and we clearly have all the expected symbol info:

```
one.typechecked.symbol = method one
one.typechecked.symbol.info = (s: String)String
```

How come `tpe` for the method is *still* coming out as `NoType`?

```
one.typechecked.tpe = NoType
```

Comment: What would you expect to get from a typed definition's tpe? Symbol's info?

Comment: Discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/fzuT5gcdM5M

Comment: @EugeneBurmako - Yes.  The tree fragment obviously has a type (as can be seen via the symbol), so I worry that when `typecheck` returns `NoType` then it's going to violate the principle of least surprise for a lot of people when coming to macros.  Perhaps extra documentation is the right answer here - both on the docs site and in the scaladoc for `typecheck`.  I wonder how much better we could do for palladium, especially given that macros (and quasiquotes) very obviously favour working with trees in preference to symbols.

Comment: Yes indeed this is confusing, which is why I created the discussion topic to figure this out once and for all. Thank you for bringing this up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how scalac works. Typechecked definitions (i.e. subclasses of `DefTree`) are assigned with `NoType`. To the contrast, untyped definitions have `null` in their `tpe` (just like other untyped trees), so it's possible to discern them.